# Does less.js support IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, less

I am going to use less.js and I doubt about Internet Explorer 9+. At LESS site they write following:

> LESS runs on both the client-side (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) and server-side...

http://lesscss.org

But there isn't IE in the list. I just want to know does anybody use less.js and there aren't problems with IE 9+?

Comment: Same doubt here... have you had any chance trying it yourself? There are a lot of blogs giving to understand that it works, but the official page denying it is a little bit disturbing...

Comment: Alex, I've worked with less.js for a month and it works OK in IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot speak about the client side, but i can recommend to use it on server side.

There are tools like [SimpleLess](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) which can generate the css files at design time, so you can place the finished css files on your server. That way you never have to worry about browser support and JavaScript, and your server has not more work to do. As a bonus you can automatically get minified css files, and you can assemble several css files into a single file.

For my sites i cannot think about writing the css files without `less` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand and agree with you. But I just want it in browser for my needs for development and I cannot use something like SimpleLess because of some conditions.

Comment: @infous - Ok that i cannot answer, never tried it out myself, sorry.

Comment: Here's an interesting info about less.js and IE http://starikovs.com/2012/11/27/does-less-js-support-ie-9-at-least/